# Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for git push error

Tags: visual-studio, git, github, bitbucket

I'm trying to get used to the [VS git plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c).
I'm using it with bitbuket and GitHub remote repositories.

Sometimes i get the following error :

```
An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
Chunked encoding upload is not supported on the HTTP/1.0 protocol.
```

Is someone knowing how to avoid this error ?

Comment: Wow - most things are HTTP 1.1 now-a-days.  Are you going through an old HTTP Proxy server?

Comment: When i got this error i was actually behind an HTTP proxy server.
I don't really know if it support HTTP 1.1, i'll ask the sysadmin.
Thx for the tip anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem came from the proxy server i had to use at work which didn't support the HTTP/1.1 protocol.

Our sysadmin confirmed me that he was using squid 2.7 and he didn't support HTTP/1.1.

Thank's again for the tip.

Comment: do you know some fix? i can not change our network to support HTTP/1.1 protocol....

Comment: @GuilhermeWaltricke I think you could use some tunneling mechanism (SSH, VPN, etc...) just to get out of the network.
I think it could work

Comment: @GuilhermeWaltricke : If you are behind corporate proxy, please try to set up the Git to work behind proxy. git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080

Comment: @VishalBhatt the issue is not to configure the proxy. But the fact that the proxy does not support HTTP/1.1

Comment: awesome.....in my case i was using fiddler with external device and that creates an impediment for me to push my changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your system proxy settings. Check in IE internet options if you are using the proxy. Disable the proxy setting from the IE Options and try to push it again. It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: For me it was because, Fiddler had changed my Proxy settings and this case was in Win 10 and whn pushing to Gitlab for sake of better SEO results

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to Fiddler monitoring requests. Once I've turned it off the problem disappeared.